# PHP array_sum - why array_sum is not working for the following script?

Tags: php, array-sum

I have seen read other posts that are almost similar to my problem. 
but I can't find the right answer to my problem.
here I have a `$data[4]` array that is like the following.

```
Array ( [0] => 0.84 ) Array ( [0] => 2.79 )
```

and this my php code for calculating the value in variable $data[4]

```
$a= array();
foreach(array($data[4]) as $datas) {
    $a[] = $datas;
}
 print_r($a); 

 $sum = array_sum($a);
 echo $sum;

}
```

but the results are not calculating, instead of displaying values ​​from the data array `$data[4]`
like this

```
0.84
2.79
```

Comment: `$a` still multi leveled, needs to be flat

Comment: Can you share your code link on https://3v4l.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You got two arrays with `0` index in `$data[4]`. You have to flatten this `$a`, you can add extra foreach.

```
$a= array();
foreach(array($data[4]) as $datas) {
    foreach($datas as $item) { // here - extra foreach
        $a[] = $item;
    }
}
 print_r($a); 

 $sum = array_sum($a);
 echo $sum;

}
```

By the way - consider using `var_export` to show more precisely what's in your data :)

Comment: not working i got eror code Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
and i done use var_export , this array data in var_export = array ( 0 => '0.84', )array ( 0 => '2.79', )

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your array is like `$data[4] = [[0.89],[2.79]]` then you can use this code to get sum.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($data[4] as $datas) {
    $sum +=  array_sum($datas);
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: @yagami-cell please provide me your data array

Comment: thanks for answer.. maybe if value $data[4] like this $data[4] = [[0.89],[2.79]].. its working.. but my value array $data[4] is Array ( [0] => 0.84 ) Array ( [0] => 2.79 ) 
.. and its not working..

Comment: Please `print_r($data[4])` & paste it in comment

Comment: Array ( [0] => 0.84 ) Array ( [0] => 2.79 )